# Path of a relativistic charge due to a (nearly) infinitely massive charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, scattering

Suppose we know the position, velocity of a charge at time $t=0$ and its rest mass is also known. It is attracted by a (nearly) infinitely massive known opposite charge which is at rest and always be at rest (because no force can move it) in our frame of reference. How can we predict the path of the moving charge? I got a differential equation which was really hard to solve especially due to the complicated force momentum relationship. The equation which I got is :
$$
m \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{\vec{u}}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{|\vec{u}|^2}{c^2}}} = k \dfrac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3}
$$
where $\vec{u}$ is the velocity of the particle, $\vec{r}$ is its position with heavy particle at origin, and $k$ is the product of charges and Coulumb law constant.

Comment: The reason for choosing very high mass is to ignore retarded potentials.

Comment: Can you please include in the question what differential equation you got, and how you got it? And, also, do you want to take into account radiative effects? I imagine you do, but just to make sure!

Comment: Can you tell me How readiative effects take place. Then I can tell you to consider or not.

Comment: When a charged particle is accelerated, it radiates energy (i.e. creates an EM field). But this might be too advanced for you, so you might just ignore it for now!

Comment: The energy of a particle is only altered when a force acts on it. And I have already considered all forces so I think I have already considered readiative effect on particles energy. Am I correct?

Comment: No, you're not, radiative effects come from considering the Maxwell equations in pressence of charges (the movement of your charge will change the electric and magnetic fields). But this probably complicates the problem beyond analytic resolubility, and I see that you haven't learned about this (you'll learn in a more advanced EM course), so don't worry about it. The problem you have is already intricate enough!

Comment: Yes I was not familiar with readiative effects. But one thing i want to know is that can energy change without any application of force and if so then is energy conserved in such a system?

Comment: In easy terms, when a force is applied to a charged particle, it accelerated (Newton's 2nd law). Now, this also changes the EM fields (Maxwell's equations), so some of the energy of the particle is "given" (radiated) to the EM fields. Bottom line, the particles accelerates less, as "some of the force is given to the EM fields".

Comment: Use the conservation of angular momentum to reduce the conservation of energy equation to a one-dimensional first-order ODE for $r(t)$.  (This is the “effective potential” approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to give you some hints for now. Everything should be familiar from when you solved the [classical two body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem).

First, you might want to rewrite your equation as
$$
m \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{\dot{\vec{r}}}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{|\dot{\vec{r}}|^2}{c^2}}} = k \dfrac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3},
$$
and do a change of variables to polar coordinates i.e. put the infinite mass in the center of your coordinate system.

Then, you might want to take a look at conserved quantities: Energy and Angular momentum (Question: How do these look in SR?)

I hope this is enough for now, and that you might be able to reach the end on your own ;)